# Run Remote Bash Script in Python

Tags: python, bash, ssh

What I'm wanting to do, is run a bash script on another computer, from python. My first thought was to SSH into my remote computer with python, and run it that way. Is there any other way of running a remote bash script in python?

Btw, the remote bash script is on the same network as my python script.

Comment: `ssh` is the way to go, look up `Paramiko` and `Fabric`

Comment: I'd prefer to do it another way. Are there any others?

Comment: Does [Python PYRO](http://pythonhosted.org/Pyro4/) help you?

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, `ssh` is the normal way to do this. If you have need to detach the other program (you don't want to just leave the `ssh` link open), have a look at `screen`. There are certainly more efficient ways to do this, but you'll have to give more information to get a more detailed answer.